# How to change stripe subscription charging immediately

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, stripes

I am making a SASS product with two subscription plans. Each plan has credits against them. Say, `basic` has 100 credits and `pro` has 200 credits. If in the middle 0f the month someone with a basic plan exhausts his 100 credits how do I charge him using stripe subscription(laravel cashier)?

Comment: What about a condition like : (!$user->subscribed('sub_name') && $user->allowedCredits() <= 0) then redirect to stripe or show button for a subscription?  So have a function with such condition and use it to decide whether to have user access or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can notify the customer that their usage ran out and offer an upgrade. You can then update the Price ID in the Subscription. You can read more here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade